# How can I determine wheter or not two curves are tangents?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, curves, tangent-line

Let $a_0,b_0 \in \mathbb{R}, a_0^2 + b_0^2 = 1$. How can I show that the curves
$$\frac{x^2}{a_0^2} + \frac{y^2}{b_0^2} = 1$$
and
$$x+y = 1$$
are tangents to eachother? I tried to find a point such that its gradient vector is equal for both curves (ie,considering $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{a_0^2} + \frac{y_2}{b_0^2}$ and $g(x,y) = x+y$). Am I wrong?

Comment: First, the curves must intersect. You calculate the gradient only at intersection points

Comment: What is $y_2$? I guess you mean $y^2$?

Comment: @JustANoob thx!!

Comment: @Andrei That's right!

Comment: The gradients don't have to be equal but they have to be co-linear and non-zero.

Comment: @blamocur: I can't make sense of your comment.

Comment: @TonyK He means that they don't have to have the same magnitude, only the same direction.

Comment: @JustANoob: Yes, I think you're right.

Comment: It seems they are indeed tangent to each other if $a_0^2+b_0^2=1$, but not if $a_0+b_0=1$. Are you sure the question is posed correctly?

Comment: @DavidQuinn you're right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving simultaneously leads to the quadratic equation $$x^2(a^2+b^2)-2a^2x+a^2-a^2b^2=0$$

The discriminant can be simplified as $$4a^2b^2(a^2+b^2-1)$$

Tangency means double roots, and this is zero since $a^2+b^2=1$

Hence the result.